# Why does VS Code often fail to parse package.json, and show syntax errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, package.json

So I've been using VS Code for several years, and this problem has persisted among many, many versions of VS Code. I'd like to understand what's going on:

When I open and edit a package.json file in any project (and ONLY a package.json--at least, this is the only file type I've noticed it happening in), VS Code frequently fails to parse the file, citing a syntax error in a random place. Example:

[image]

The thing is, there is no syntax error. Here's another screenshot, without the error message:

[image]

Sometimes the "red squiggle" is at the beginning of the file, sometimes it's near the end. I can't seem to find a pattern there.

It looks to me like VS Code is getting a truncated version of the file, parsing it, and discovering incomplete or missing pieces.

Am I the only one having this issue? How do I discover what's going on and why?

Update: Here's another screenshot, as it's been happening again. I don't even understand what plugin is doing this--maybe it's a vscode built-in parser?

[image]

Version info:
Version: 1.49.3
Commit: 2af051012b66169dde0c4dfae3f5ef48f787ff69
Date: 2020-10-02T17:54:06.165Z
Electron: 9.2.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0

Comment: what is the error at `@babel/core`? Strange that the code in the Parse error does not match the code in the editor. The 2 closing `}` are in the error. What if you look at the file with vim, `od` or the Hex editor, are there strange characters in the file?

Comment: @rioV8 I wish I could check, but I've since closed the file and re-opened it and the problem is gone. (This happens regularly--seems to go away on its own, then comes back again in a new place, marking the whole file as syntactically incorrect).

Comment: I may have found the cause! Apparently this is a years-old bug in the Textmate Languages plugin: https://github.com/Togusa09/vscode-tmlanguage/issues/14

Comment: That plugin has had no update for more than 2 years and there is a fix proposed in PR #20